# How to download files from the AWS Glacier storage directly to local PC using NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-glacier, aws-sdk-nodejs

I am using the AWS Glacier storage to store my older files by aws-sdk for Node js. I am able to upload the file from local PC to storage but couldn't download it from storage to the Local.

Is there any way to write a code to download files directly to the local not to S3?

```
var params = {
    accountId: "example", 
    jobParameters: {
        Description: "My inventory job", 
        Type: "inventory-retrieval"
    }, 
    vaultName: "example",
};



glacier.initiateJob(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    else {

        console.log("job initated job successfully", data);    

        var params = {
            accountId: "example", 
            jobId: 'example', 
            vaultName: "example"
        };
        glacier.describeJob(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
            else  {
                console.log('Job description ', data);      


                var params = {
                accountId: "example", 
                jobId: 'example',  
                vaultName: "example"
                };
                glacier.getJobOutput(params, function(err, data) {
                if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
                else     console.log(data);           // successful response

                });


            }

        })
    }


});
```

Comment: why are you not using the instead AWS cli and glacier api to upload and download file. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/glacier/index.html https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-services-glacier.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I am going to use it in website for all the users and the awscli is not fitting in my requirements.

Comment: ok got it i had doubt only why you are using node . there no documentation aws using java script to archive the data. you can generate the support ticket  and ask them

Comment: data retrieval from s3 glacier take time so why you want to store data in glacier class ? of you want to Upload and download data simply use simple class in s3.for retrieval of data from glacier it will take time

Comment: I am already using a EFS for real time storage purpose. For a back up and a cost optimization, I need to store it in a cold storage. I am going to delete it from EFS after user's one month is completed and store it into the Glacier.

Comment: nice great idea

Comment: as per my knowledge s3 is cheaper then EFS.